# Hive throws Error for Aggregate function

Tags: apache, hive, hadoop2, hue

When i try to execute a non-Aggregate command using Hive,the query seems to work fine,something as below:

select  * from airlines_analysis.airline;
select  airline.month  from airlines_analysis.airline;

But when i execute an Aggregate command, something as below:

select count(distinct uniquecarrier) from airlines_analysis.airline;

i face the below issue:

org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698) at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Hive is this?
Are you using Tez engine? Tez sometimes behaves weird when dealing with huge data sets. try this

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
select count(distinct uniquecarrier) from airlines_analysis.airline;
```